# Android Studio Line-Segment intersection / collision

Tags: java, android

Can I get a clarification on how to figure out the point in which 2 line segments intersect?

I have this code in which I am creating a pong game but I am having trouble with figuring out where the ball intersects with the paddle and if so basically bounce it back. I know some basic algebra is needed but for the sake of my code what is needed?

I have the current position of the ball, the old position of the ball, and the paddles current position (ballX,Y , oldBallX,Y , etc) What would I have to do to get the (x, y) intersection point for the collision of the ball on the paddle?

**CODE**

`

```
package com.example.pong;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;


public class PongView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {


    private static final String TAG = "";
    private final GameActivity gameActivity;

    private Thread _thread;

    private int screenWidth;    // screen width
    private int screenHeight;   // screen height

    Context _context;

    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;

    private boolean _run = false;

    //  All pong variables go in here
    // Right Paddle
    private float rPaddle; // variable set by touch event
    // Left Paddle
    private float lPaddle; // variable set by touch event
    // Paddle variables
    private int halfPaddle = 50;



    private final static int MAX_FPS = 30; //desired fps
    private final static int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS; // the frame period

    private Paint background = new Paint();
    private Paint dark = new Paint();

    private float ballX = 500.0f; // ball location
    private float ballY = 250.0f;
    /// pongSpeed variables
    public float pongSpeed = 1.0f;
    private long mLastTime = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private float timeElapsed; // Time since last frame in seconds

    // The speed in pixels per second
    private float ballSpeedX = 300.0f;
    private float ballSpeedY = 300.0f;

    // Variables for current pong position
    private float oldBallX = 0.0f;
    private float oldBallY = 0.0f;

    private float xPos = 0.0f;
    private float yPos = 0.0f;
    private float xDir = 1.0f;
    private float yDir = 1.0f;

    //



    public PongView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.gameActivity = (GameActivity) context;

        _context = context;

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }

    //
    public void setRPaddle(float rp) {
        synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
            rPaddle = rp;
        }
    }


    public void setLPaddle(float lp) {
        synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
            lPaddle = lp;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
         float avg_sleep = 0.0f;
         float fcount = 0.0f;
         long fps = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);


                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    // Update game state
                    update();
                }
                // draw image
                drawImage(c);

            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }

            }

            float deltaTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - started);
            int sleepTime = (int) (FRAME_PERIOD - deltaTime);



            if (sleepTime > 0) {
                try {
                   _thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        _run = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // try again shutting down the thread
            }
        }
    }

    public void initialize(int w, int h) {
        screenWidth = w;
        screenHeight = h;

        // create paints, rectangles, init time, etc

        background.setColor(0xff200040);  // should really get this from resource file
        dark.setColor(0xffdddddd);

    }

    protected void update() {
        // game update goes here

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        MediaPlayer pip = MediaPlayer.create(_context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.lil_pip);


        long now = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Current time
        if (now > mLastTime)
        {
            timeElapsed =  (now - mLastTime) / 1000.0f;
        }
        mLastTime = now;

        ballX += ballSpeedX * timeElapsed;
        ballY += ballSpeedY * timeElapsed;

    oldBallX = ballX;
        oldBallY = ballY;


        collisionCheck();
    
    //Treat paddle as line segment.   Treat ball positions as points.
    //Change ball direction if the two line segments intersect.



    }




    protected void collisionCheck()
    {

        // Bounce right side
        if ((ballX > screenWidth) && (ballSpeedX > 0.0f))
        {
            ballSpeedX *= -1.0f;
            pip.start();
        }
        // Bounce left side
        // Not sure if using "80 *" is the best
        if ((80 * ballX < screenHeight) && (ballSpeedX < 0.0f))
        {
            ballSpeedX *= -1.0f;
            pip.start();
        }
        // Bounce bottom side
        if ((ballY > screenHeight) && (ballSpeedY > 0.0f))
        {
            ballSpeedY *= -1.0f;
            pip.start();
        }
        // Bounce top side
        // Not sure if using "80 *" is the best
        if ((80 * ballY < screenHeight) && (ballSpeedY < 0.0f))
        {
            ballSpeedY *= -1.0f;
            pip.start();
        }

        Log.d("TAG", "Ball is moving");
    }


    private void rightPaddle (Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(7 * screenWidth / 8, rPaddle * screenHeight + halfPaddle,
                 7 * screenWidth / 8 + 15, rPaddle * screenHeight - halfPaddle, dark);
    }


    private void leftPaddle (Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRect( screenWidth / 8, lPaddle * screenHeight + halfPaddle,
                screenWidth / 8 + 15, lPaddle * screenHeight - halfPaddle, dark);
    }

    private void pongBall (Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(ballX, ballY, ballX + 10, ballY + 10, dark);

    }


    protected void drawImage(Canvas canvas) {

        if (canvas == null) return;

        // Draw commands go here
        // Draw commands go here

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);

        pongBall(canvas);

        rightPaddle(canvas);
        leftPaddle(canvas);


    }




    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        screenWidth = w;
        screenHeight = h;

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        initialize(w, h);
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        _run = true;
        _thread = new Thread(this);
        _thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        _run = false;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int numPointers = event.getPointerCount();
        int ptrIdx = 0;

        while (ptrIdx < numPointers) {
            int id = event.getPointerId(ptrIdx);
            float xp = event.getX(ptrIdx) / screenWidth;

            if (xp > 0.6) {
                setRPaddle(event.getY(ptrIdx) / screenHeight);
            } else if (xp < 0.4) {
                setLPaddle(event.getY(ptrIdx) / screenHeight);
            }

            if ((ptrIdx > 0) || (id > 0)) {
                Log.i(TAG, " Feel the power..." + ptrIdx + " " + id);
            }

            ptrIdx++;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

`

I've tried making the paddles into Path's but my confusion is what exactly am I using for x1, x2, y1, y2 to find out the point of intersection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know some basic algebra knowledge. A line can be written in the form of `Ax + By + C = 0` in a plain. (See [Wikipedia-Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)))

To calculate the intersect, you may first calculate the equation of the two lines.

A line passing from `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` can be written in the form of `(y1 - y2) * x + (x2 - x1) * y + (x1 * y2 - x2 * y1) = 0`. This way, you can calculate the equation of the two lines.

Now, you get the equation of the two lines. Say `A1 * x + B1 * y + C1 = 0` and `A2 * x + B2 * y + C2 = 0`. Then the x-coordinate of the intersect will be `(C2 * B1 - C1 * B2) / (A1 * B2 - A2 * B1)`, and the y-coordinate will be `(C1 * A2 - C2 * A1) / (A1 * B2 - A2 * B1)`. Thus, you get the intersect.